# Spark executor configuration

Tags: apache-spark

As per My spark cluster the below configuration is set

```
spark.executor.memory=2g
```

I would like to know that this 2G of RAM is shared by all executors or this 2G of RAM is used by each executor in each worker machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know that this 2G of RAM is shared by all executors or
>   this 2G of RAM is used by each executor in each worker machine

This setting will cause each executor on every one of your Worker nodes to have 2G memory. This setting **doesn't mean** *"share 2G of memory between all executors"*, it **means** *"give each executor 2G of memory"*.

This is explicitly stated in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> spark.executor.memory | 1g |  Amount of memory to use **per executor process**
>   (e.g. 2g, 8g).

If you have multiple executors per Worker node, this means that each one of these executors will consume 2G of memory.

Comment: Is that possible to have multiple executors in a same worker node?.By default How many executors are configured in a worker node?